# How insert data in an ONNX as float32[N,60,1] in ML.NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ml.net, onnx

I'm using ML.NET and I want to insert as input a **float32[N, 60, 1]**(as in the picture). I don't figure how to pass the data. I'm trying with this class:

```
public class OnnxInput
{
    [ColumnName("lstm_input")]
    public float lstm_input { get; set; }
}

var input = new OnnxInput[length][];

// Here I load the data into the input variable

var dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(input);
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.
            ApplyOnnxModel(
                    modelFile: modelLocation,
                    inputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelInput },
                    outputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelOutput }
                );
var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
```

creating this matrix, when I try to fit the data into the pipeline I have the error: **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member SyncRoot (Parameter 'rawType')'**

Trying with another approach, with this input class:

```
public class OnnxInput
{
    [ColumnName("lstm_input")]
    public float[] lstm_input { get; set; }
}

var input = new OnnxInput[realLength];

// Here I load the data into the input variable

var dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(input);
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.
            ApplyOnnxModel(
                    modelFile: modelLocation,
                    inputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelInput },
                    outputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelOutput }
                );
var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
```

creating this matrix, when I try to fit the data into the pipeline I have the error: **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Variable length input columns not supported'**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable input error (**Variable length input columns not supported**) just means your model is expecting a fixed sized input. Specifically, you can add the attribute `[VectorType(60, 1)]` on top of the property `lstm_input` in `OnnxInput` class.

Comment: why float[N, 60, 1] is represented as just [VectorType(60, 1)]? How about N? And how to represent the output float32[ N, 1 ]? I'm stuck on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75022045/ml-net-how-to-define-shape-vectors-for-gpt2-onnx-model If you could help I would thank you!

Comment: because N is not known (think about it as the model being called N times to perform a prediction). 60 is the number of features the model needs to do a prediction. The output is a single value, right? Then it shouldn't need an attribute